# SWT label and Clabel does not render '&' character correctly

Tags: swt, rcp

I am trying to display & which is in my string using SWT label/Clabel however both of them  ignore & character Below is the same code which can reproduce this issue

```java
 import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
 import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
 import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
 import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
 import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

 public class LabelDemo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     final Display display = new Display();
     final Shell shell = new Shell(display, SWT.SHELL_TRIM);
     shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
 Label label=new Label(shell, SWT.BORDER);
     label.setText("text &the label");

    // label.setImage(new Image(display,"yourFile.gif"));
     shell.open();
     // Set up the event loop.
     while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
       if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
         // If no more entries in event queue
         display.sleep();
       }
     }
     display.dispose();
   }

 }
```

Am I doing something wrong here .Any clue on it will be helpful .

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the rootcause why it was skipping the & or mnemonic character in label .we need to  escape it by putting an extra & so that it will be rendered